# do states in react suffer from async effects

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I'm trying to set set state variables and it seems to occur spottily at best. I tried putting in an async/await in react.useEffect, but the notes in the interpreter on the inspect console said to try that directly instead. so I try that on useState and useState's intellsense says "async has no effect on this method." How can I get my userInfo variable populated consistently so that I can use the value as intended?:

```
function Support() {


  const [userInfo, updateInfo] = React.useState(null);


  React.useEffect(() => {
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      .then( currentUser => updateInfo({ userInfo: {name: currentUser.username, id: currentUser.attributes.sub }}))
      .catch(err => console.log({ err }))

  }, []);
  


    
  return (


    <div>
    <div>Support</div>
    <div>
        username?: {userInfo.name}<br/>
         User id?: {userInfo.id}
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

the browser complains about the attributes missing but I've seen them before sometimes when the response populates as intended.  This is my current (unhelpful for me) stacktrace:

[image]

Here's what I've updated it to (still not working unfortunately):

```
  return (


    <div>
    <div>Support</div>
    <div>
        username?: {userInfo.name ?? "Loading... "}<br/>
         User id?: {userInfo.id ?? "Loading... "}
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: `const [userInfo, updateInfo] = React.useState(null);` The first render is always going have null for the state. You need to check for that before trying to access `userInfo.name` and render something else. Maybe `{userInfo?.name ?? 'Loading...'}`, or maybe the entire component could return `null`.

Comment: should I set it to some 'dummy' value that will be updated later such as 'loading'?

Comment: `null` is a good dummy value, you just need to check for it. If `"loading"` makes things easier, you could do that.

Comment: in your render method you try to display the user details as soon as the page has loaded, independent of the state of the userinfo variable. 
Only render the details when the user info details have been updated, for example like that: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but I'm still getting: 

Support.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')

Comment: I missed the question mark at the beginning of userInfo?.name @NicholasTower.  OK if you can stretch that out into an answer I'll accept as yours was first and got me going, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add dependency array to useEffect otherwise it'll be called frequently.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
function Support() {

 const [userInfo, updateInfo] = React.useState({name: "" ,id: "" });


  React.useEffect(() => {
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      .then( currentUser => updateInfo({name: currentUser.username, id: currentUser.attributes.sub }))
      .catch(err => console.log({ err }))

  },[]);
  


    
  return (


    <div>
        <div>Support</div>
        <div>
        Username : {userInfo.name} <br/>
        User Id  : {userInfo.id}
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

or

```
function Support() {

 const [userInfo, updateInfo] = React.useState(null);


  React.useEffect(() => {
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      .then( currentUser => updateInfo({name: currentUser.username, id: currentUser.attributes.sub }))
      .catch(err => console.log({ err }))

  },[]);
  


    
  return (


    <div>
        <div>Support</div>
        <div>
        Username : {userInfo.name? userInfo.name : ""} <br/>
        User Id  : {userInfo.id? userInfo.id : ""}
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

I think you can use one of these methods.